# Why does the same key function produce different results for sorted vs list.sort?

Tags: python

My mission is to sort the list by the frequency of numbers included in it. If a few numbers have an equal frequency - they should be sorted according to their natural order.
For example: `[5, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3]` ==> `[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
During the process of solving the problem, I wrote a function as follow:

```
lista = [3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]
def func1(numbers: list):
    numbers.sort(key=lambda x:(-numbers.count(x), x))
    return numbers
    
result = func1(lista)
print(result)
```

but the result is `[3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 7, 11, 11, 13]`,
and then I wrote a function very similar to that

```
lista = [3, 4, 11, 13, 11, 4, 4, 7, 3]
def func2(numbers: list):
    return sorted(numbers,key=lambda x:(-numbers.count(x), x))

result = func2(lista)
print(result)
```

the result is `[4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 11, 11, 7, 13]`, which is what I wanted
My question is: what's different between list.sort function and sorted function

it is just a few part of my whole homework, please ignore the time complexity of my algorithm.

Comment: I've taken the liberty to adjust the title to match what the body aiming at. You can [edit] the question again or rollback the change if you feel it does not match your intention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `list.sort` is an in-place algorithm, the content of the list *during* its `.sort` is arbitrary – an algorithm might have the list partially sorted, keep sorted items independently, or even behave differently depending on the "unsortedness". As a result, a `key` accessing a list during its `.sort` is not guaranteed to work as expected.

In specific, CPython makes the list appear empty during its `.sort`:

> ##### [sort(*, key=None, reverse=False)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort)
>
> **CPython implementation detai**l: While a list is being sorted, the
> effect of attempting to mutate, or even inspect, the list is
> undefined. The C implementation of Python *makes the list appear empty
> for the duration*, and raises ValueError if it can detect that the list
> has been mutated during a sort.

In contrast, `sorted` guarantees to produce a new `list`, leaving the old list unmodified and consistent in appearance during sorting.

---

You can inspect this behaviour by observing the key before using it:

```py
def observe(arg, *hint):
    """Helper to inspect a value during its usage"""
    print(repr(arg), *hint)
    return arg

numbers = [1, 2, 1]
numbers.sort(key=lambda x: observe(numbers.count(x), "is the key for", x))
# 0 is the key for 1
# 0 is the key for 2
# 0 is the key for 1
sorted(numbers, key=lambda x: observe(numbers.count(x), "is the key for", x))
# 2 is the key for 1
# 1 is the key for 2
# 2 is the key for 1
```

Using the key function `key=lambda x: (-numbers.count(x), x)` in `.sort` means the key is of the form `(0, x)` – since the first key-part `0` is always equal, items are sorted by the second key-part, i.e. their value. This is equivalent to the standard sort key.

Comment: Wow I have been tricked by "The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated once and then used for the entire sorting process." in the documentation! They say the key is calculated once, but didn't say when!

Comment: I wrongly thought that The key corresponding to each item in the list is calculated before the `list.sort` and `sorted` once and use the result the whole process of the sort. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about the difference between `list.sort()` and `sorted(list)`:

They both sort the list you want. But `list.sort()` changes the original `list` object (changes the indices) while `sorted(list)` doesn't effect `list` itself but. I guess you'd want to create another object from the `sorted()` function if you didn't want to change the original list. For example, `list2 = sorted(list)`

Comment: This doesn't seem to address why the result of sorting appears to be different. Can you elaborate on that perhaps?